# Fetch folder names and total read/unread in a single query

Tags: php, mysql

My SQL database structure is as follows...

**email_folders**

```
id, name
```

**email_messages**

```
id, id_folder, date, date_read
```

In a single MySQL query I'm trying to get the folder names, their total email messages count both email total count and unread count per folder.

Thus far I have the basic counting bit down though the returned array in PHP returns the number of rows that there are emails for *and* undesirably does *not* return all the folders from the folders from the `email_folders` table.

Here is what I currently have...

```
SELECT 
ef.name, 
(SELECT count(id) FROM email_messages WHERE id_folder=ef.id AND date_read<date) AS unread, 
(SELECT count(id) FROM email_messages WHERE id_folder=ef.id) AS total 
FROM email_messages AS em
LEFT JOIN email_folders AS ef ON ef.id=em.id_folder;
```

There are currently four folders though over a hundred rows are returned so I know I'm doing something wrong. I'll be happy to make any necessary clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    f.name FolderName,
    count(m.id) TotalMessagesCount,
    sum(m.date_read < m.date) TotalUnreadMessagesCount
from email_folders f
left join email_messages m on f.id = m.id_folder
group by f.id
```

I really wonder why `date_read < date` means `Unread` for you. Having the date_read set to null makes more sense to me be considered as `Unread`.

Comment: This is very close, I have 104 total, 103 in inbox, 1 in spam, 0 in sent/drafts. This returns 1 for all folders (including the two empty) even though there is nothing in those folders.

Comment: That's strange. Please, double check. The count(m.id) should return 0 whenever a folder is empty.